# CSS to make image's overflow visible is applied but has no effect on browsers other than Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

**PAGE I NEED HELP WITH**

All pages containing product cards. Example *(scroll down below the product details)*:

https://www.gxbeachtennis.com.br/loja/raquetes/gx/raquete-profissional-gx-dynamic/

**SITUATION**

I am using the snippet below, added via the **Code Snippets** plugin, in order to move down the image that appears when the user hovers over the product card so that the product is visible.

It works and the image is moved down, but the part of the image that I wanted to show remains invisible.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
const imageWrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.woocommerce-image__wrapper');

for (let i = 0; i < imageWrappers.length; i++) {
    const wrapperHeight = imageWrappers[i].offsetHeight;
    const image = imageWrappers[i].querySelector('.gallery-image');
    image.style.paddingTop = `${0.68 * wrapperHeight}px`;
    image.style.overflow = visible; /*EVEN AFTER I ADDED THIS IT DOESN'T WORK*/
}
```

**CSS (added in Customizer)**

```
div.woocommerce-image__wrapper > a > img.gallery-image
{
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

`overflow: visible` works as expected on Google Chrome:

[image]

But not on any other browser (this is FireFox):

[image]

**MORE DETAILS**

The style seems to have been successfully applied, but still takes no effect

[image]

Comment: The problem is probably caused by `image.style.paddingTop = ${0.68 * wrapperHeight}px` that extra padding is pushing the content down leaving large space on the top

Comment: Hi Konekoya! Thanks a lot for replying. Yes, that's the idea. It is pushed down by the JS code so that the other part becomes visible and the paddle's design can be seen in the product cards. That's expected. The problem is that `overflow: visible`, works perfectly on Chrome to make the cut-off part visible but not on any other browser (see the first photo, which looks the way it should. That's using Chrome. Unfortunately the second photo, which was taken while using Firefox, is still cut off).

Comment: Try removing that padding when hovering the images, I removed that padding it fixed the issue in Firebox for me.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. In the end I just deactivated the snippet and went with the image in its normal location. Thanks a lot for your time and have a great rest of the week